# Declaring 'countries visited' at immigration after travelling with dual citizenship

Tags: customs-and-immigration, dual-nationality, passport-stamps

I will travel on holiday to several countries eventually using both passports of my dual citizenship. When I return to my home country and enter immigration, I will need to fill in an entry declaration form listing the countries I have been to during my trip.

The passport of my home country will only have stamps / visas from some of the countries I visited. On the declaration form, do I need to fill in all the countries from both passports, or just the ones visited using the passport of my home country?

Comment: Depends on if your dual citizenship is allowed or not.

Comment: Hi, welcome to TSE. Please add which countries you are a citizen of, which countries you will be visiting, and which countries you are unsure about.

Comment: It is always wise to tell the truth, ie: list all the countries you visited.  There shouldn't be any issues unless: 1) you're not allowed to hold dual citizenship; 2) country A prohibits you from visiting XYZ that you entered on country B's passport.

Comment: @GayotFow You're "treble"?

Comment: @Azor-Ahai Yeah, and I'm bass. You didn't know?

Comment: Some countries are well-known to not commonly stamp passports. Your home country probably knows about a few of them, and also knows that things change and that sometimes passports just don't get stamped.

Answer (score 24):

The form is about where *you* have been, not where your passport has been, so **you should list all countries**.

Since you're returning to your home country, Immigration is not really going to care where you have been. Customs, however, may be interested in this, and things will get awkward if you don't declare country X, but they find goods obviously purchased from country X.

This answer assumes that your home country is OK both with dual citizenship and you visiting country X. If this is not the case, things get complicated, and you'll have to weigh the potential risk of a false declaration vs. getting busted for a second citizenship or consorting with 'the enemy'.

Comment: Security services are going to care where you have been (and if they find you to have been somewhere you didn't declare, you may be in deepest troubles), and sometimes the health department (e.g. CDC) also may want to find everyone who has been in/returned from a certain country in a specific time frame.